# C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Tags: javascript, docker, artificial-intelligence, blockchain

i am trying to run a docker image i got it from git hub .i getting the this error, i tried in windows docker treminal

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
```

this is the docker image :

```
docker run --rm -it -p 3000:3000 -p 5387:5387 -p 7545:7545 -v ${PWD}:/root/workspace/demo -v /root/workspace/demo/node_modules -v /root/workspace/demo/client/node_modules --name decai-demo mcr.microsoft.com/s
amples/blockchain-ai/0xdeca10b-demo bash
```